# Fade out of background page with JQuery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, fadeout

l want to create a dropdwon menu like the one on the [**Edinburgh Zoo**](http://www.edinburghzoo.org.uk/) site which fades out the page in the background when it is in action.

Have this so far.. **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fififreckles/xhk5vkjz/3/)** I can't figure out how I would get the background to fade, any ideas?

```
var stop = true;
var hovered;
var timeout;

$('.nav').hover(
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        stop = true;
        hovered = this;
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        if($(hovered).hasClass('nav_menu_link_drop')){
            $('.content').css('z-index',0);
            $(hovered).next('.content').css('z-index',5);        
            $(hovered).next('.content').slideDown(350);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                $('.content').not($(hovered).next('.content')).slideUp(350);  
            },200);
        }
        else
            $('.content').slideUp(350);    
        },400);
    },
    function(e){
        stop = false;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        setTimeout(function(){
            if(!stop)
                $('.content').slideUp(350);
        },500);
    }
);

$('.content').hover(
    function(){
        stop = true;    
    },
    function(){

    }
);

$('#nav_menu').hover(
    function(){

    },
    function(){
        timeout = setTimeout(function(){
            $('.content').slideUp(350);
        },200);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a new `element` that will act as a `back-drop` effect.

**E.g.**

Put this code inside the bottom of the `body` tag.

```
<div class="back-drop"></div>
```

Then assign `css properties` to it.

```
.back-drop {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Also, add `z-index: 9999;` to `#nav_menu` in your css.

```
#nav_menu {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    background: orange;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Add this code to your **jquery** codes.

```
$('.nav_menu_link_drop').hover(
        function() {
            $('.back-drop').css('display', 'block');
        },
        function() {
            $('.back-drop').css('display', 'none');

        }
);
```

Also, add `$('.back-drop').css('display', 'block');` and `$('.back-drop').css('display', 'none');` to your `$('.content').hover();`.

```
$('.content').hover(
        function() {
            $('.back-drop').css('display', 'block');
            stop = true;
        },
        function() {
            $('.back-drop').css('display', 'none');
        }
);
```

**Here's the [JsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/albertonaperijr/xhk5vkjz/4/).**

Hope it helps.